# Vagrant - Unable to up instance due to "librarian" not found (even though it's installed)

Tags: ruby, vagrant, rubygems

Quite a strange problem I'm having, basically I type "vagrant up" and I'm immediately presented with:

```
Gem "Librarian" was not found. Try running `vagrant gem install librarian --no-ri --no-rdoc`
```

Of course typing the above command (with or without sudo) makes no difference. And in fact librarian is already installed, see the list here:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.13)
actionpack (3.2.13)
activemodel (3.2.13, 3.2.12)
activerecord (3.2.13)
activeresource (3.2.13)
activesupport (3.2.13, 3.2.12)
addressable (2.3.4, 2.3.3)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2)
berkshelf (1.1.6)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.5)
bunny (0.7.9)
capistrano (2.14.2)
celluloid (0.13.0)
chef (11.4.0, 10.16.2)
childprocess (0.3.9)
chozo (0.6.1)
erubis (2.7.0)
faraday (0.8.7, 0.8.6)
ffi (1.7.0, 1.5.0)
hashie (2.0.3)
highline (1.6.18, 1.6.16)
hike (1.2.2)
hipchat (0.8.0)
httparty (0.11.0, 0.10.2)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
ipaddress (0.8.0)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.7, 1.6.1)
librarian (0.1.0)
log4r (1.1.10)
mail (2.5.3)
mime-types (1.22, 1.21)
minitar (0.5.4)
mixlib-authentication (1.3.0)
mixlib-cli (1.3.0)
mixlib-config (1.1.2)
mixlib-log (1.6.0, 1.4.1)
mixlib-shellout (1.1.0)
moneta (0.6.0)
multi_json (1.7.2, 1.7.1)
multi_xml (0.5.3)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
net-http-persistent (2.8)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.6.7, 2.2.2)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
net-ssh-multi (1.1)
ohai (6.16.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.13)
railsless-deploy (1.1.0, 1.0.2)
railties (3.2.13)
rake (10.0.4)
rdoc (3.12.2)
rest-client (1.6.7)
ridley (0.6.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.1.1)
rvm (1.11.3.7)
solve (0.4.2)
sprockets (2.2.2)
systemu (2.5.2)
thor (0.18.1, 0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.7)
timers (1.1.0)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.37)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
vagrant (1.0.7)
vagrant-librarian (0.1.1)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

And here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'vagrant'
gem 'librarian'
gem 'vagrant-librarian'
gem "berkshelf", "~>1.1.0"
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can proceed next? I'm really at a loss on how to get this working. I've also tried "bundle update" and "bundle install" but that didn't help.

Note: I'm on OS X 10.8.2 with vagrant 1.0.6 and ruby 1.8.7

Thanks in advance!
~ Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in Vagrantfile, you'll find that error message. It's a catch-all error for when any exception is raised. If the gem fails to load for any reason, it will send this error message. Since it specifies librarian version 0.0.26, if a different version of the gem is installed, it will fail with the same error.

Fix is to update the Gemfile and specify the librarian version needed:

```
gem 'librarian', '~> 0.0.26'
```

Then

```
bundle update
```

and finally

```
vagrant up
```